# Pandas Dataframe - replace value with boolean mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with a column named 'Temperature'

```
data = {'Day':  [1,2,3,4],
        'Temperature': [20,30,40,50]
        }
```

Now, I don't want the temperature digit but to assign '1' to the cell where Temperature is within the range of 25 to 45.  If it is not, I will assign 0 to it.

My desired dataframe is

```
    data = {'Day':  [1,2,3,4],
        'Temperature': [0,1,1,0]
        }
```

I have a boolean mask like below:

```
df[(df['Temperature']<=45) & (df['Temperature']>=25)]
```

How to use Boolean mask to achieve this?  Or, What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is convert boolean mask to `0,1` by cast to integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Temperature'] = ((df['Temperature']<=45) & (df['Temperature']>=25)).astype(int)

df['Temperature'] = np.where(df['Temperature']<=45) & (df['Temperature']>=25), 1, 0)
```

Similar solution with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df['Temperature'] = df['Temperature'].between(25, 45).astype(int)

df['Temperature'] = np.where(df['Temperature'].between(25, 45), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {'Day':  [1,2,3,4],
        'Temperature': [20,30,40,50]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[(df['Temperature']<=45) & (df['Temperature']>=25)] = 1
df[(df['Temperature']>=45) & (df['Temperature']>=25)] = 0
```